# Call an instruction on a specific core in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I know that I can call a function on a selected set of cores in Linux kernel by using `smp_call_function_single()` [1].

What if I only want to execute an instruction, say `rdmsr`, on a specific core?

I know that I can wrap it as a function, but I think it is too expensive since I only execute one instruction.

Does anyone know if it is possible to call an instruction on a specific core in Linux kernel or Xen kernel?

Thank you very much for your help!

[1] http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/smp.c#L271.

Comment: Is this part of your program **actually perfomance-critical** (that is, you have **made experiments**, and found this part to be **bottleneck**)? If not, just wrap the instruction into the function. Cross-cpu interaction is much more expensive than possible perfomance hit from wrapping. From the other side, wrapping into function is clear and steady to future kernel's changes.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you very much for your reply! Good point! Right now, it is not in the hot path. However, I'm unsure if I will move it to the hot path, such as the scheduler logic or not. So I was wondering if it is possible and I'm curious how it should be implemented if it is possible. (I want to gain more knowledge. ;-) ) I wrapped it up in a function right now, as you suggested.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't quite understand why cross-cpu interaction is much more expensive. Would you mind if you could share some pointers about  the cross-cpu interaction? Thank you very much!

Comment: One CPU has no means to **directly** force other CPU to do something. The only thing it can is setting some shared variable to callback function, so other CPU will check that variable at some point and will call this function. But interacting through shared variable requires *at very least* using atomic instructions, and these instructions have much more cost than simple function call.

Comment: Hmm, if it uses a per_cpu variable and use IPI to notify the remote cpu, it will not require the atomic instruction, will it? Since the parameters used for the function will only be used by one cpu, it should not cause race condition, if I'm correct. :-)

Comment: per-cpu variable can help to evade using atomic instructions and memory barriers only if this variable is **written only by owner CPU**. If variable is *written by other CPUs*, they compete for this variable and should use some sync for preserve correct variable's value.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Nice comment! Yeah, you are right! :-)